# A certain town with a population of 100,000 has 3 newspapers I, II,III, the proportions are as follows:

Tags: probability

I= 10 percent

II= 30% percent

II=5 percent

I&II=8 percent

I&III=2 percent

II&III=4 percent

I&II&III=1 percent

How many people read at least two newspapers? Well it would seem to me that it would 15,000 or 8+2+4+1. It is however 12,000 I have no idea how this comes to be....Pictures, equations would be great

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}&P(A \cap B \cap C)+ P(A \cap B \cap C^c) + P(A \cap B^c \cap C) + P(A^c \cap B \cap C)\\&=[P(A \cap B \cap C)+ P(A \cap B \cap C^c)] + P(A \cap B^c \cap C) + P(A^c \cap B \cap C)
\\&=P(A \cap B) + [P(A \cap C) -P(A \cap B \cap C)]+[P(B \cap C) -P(A \cap B \cap C)]
\\&=P(A \cap B)+ P(A \cap C)+P(B \cap C)-2P(A \cap B \cap C)
\\&=0.08+0.02+0.04-2(0.01) \\&=0.12\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

When you add the three numbers $8+2+4$ for I&II, I&III, and II&III, you have actually counted the people who read all three papers *three* times.  You should really only count them once, so you need to *subtract* the two overcounts, not count them again.  So the correct count is $8+2+4-2\cdot1=12$.

Another way to get the correct answer is to change I&II=8, I&III=2, and II&III=4 into I&II-*only*=7, I&III-*only*=1, and II&III-*only*=3 (i.e., subtract the I&II&III=1 from each count, to get counts of people who read exactly two papers), then add all four numbers, $7+1+3+1=12$.